# Svelte removing element not working from list of elements

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I want to remove child element from list of elements based on user click, It worked well before adding custom component inside each

```
{#each list as item}
    <div on:click={(event) => remove(item)}> {item} </div>
{/each}
```

After adding child component last element removed instead of clicked element

```
<script>
    import Child from './Child.svelte';

    let name = 'world';
    let list = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"]
    
    const remove = (item) => {
        console.log(item)
        if(item){
    list = list.filter(t => t !== item);
  }
 }
</script>
{#each list as item}
<div on:click={(event) => remove(item)}> <Child item={item}/> </div>
{/each}
```

Here I have added my child component.

```
<script>
 export let item;
    const a = item.slice(0,6)
</script>

<p >{a} </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your child component you are slicing the item after that you are using it in your child component.

```
export let item;
const a = item.slice(0,6)
```

Svelte needs to find the key to remove the selected element

Add key in each it will work.

```
{#each list as item (item)}
<div on:click={(event) => remove(item)}> <Child item={item}/> </div>
{/each}
```

Comment: It's not about the index, it's about the key expression which identifies the items. You can drop `index` and keep `(item)`. [See docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-each)

Comment: Ok Thank you, will update the answer